# OpenCV, use estimateRigidTransform to transform a contour

Tags: opencv

Ok here's my scenario. I built a paper detection app that finds a piece of paper in an image. It doesn't work 100% of the time, given white balance and focusing changes, so if we found a sheet of paper in frame 1, we want to show a border around it in frame 2 (in reality there can be many frame gap), even if we didn't find it in frame 2. In order to do so, we keep the old image, and old 4 point contour from frame 1.

Then, in frame N where we did not find a convex contour, we want to transform the old contour using an affine transformation that we compute using estimageRigidTransform.

I am 100% positive that my math is slightly off, but I'm not sure where:

```
// new image = 3200 x 6400
// old image = 3200 x 6400
// old contour = contour found in old image, same scale
vector<cv::Point> transformContourWithNewImage(Mat & newImage, Mat & oldImage, vector<cv::Point> oldContour) {
    CGFloat ratio = newImage.size().height / 500.0;
    cv::Size outputSize = cv::Size(newImage.size().width / ratio, 500);
    Mat image_copy;
    resize(newImage, image_copy, outputSize); //shrink images down so that computations are cheaper
    Mat oldImage_copy = cv::Mat();
    resize(oldImage, oldImage_copy, outputSize);
    cv::Mat transform = estimateRigidTransform(image_copy, oldImage_copy, false);
    vector<cv::Point> transformedPoints;
    cv::transform(oldContour, transformedPoints, transform);
    return transformedPoints;
}
```

I think that I need to scale the transform, since it was done on a smaller image than the contour vector represents. I also get a crash saying  my transform Mat has the wrong number of rows/cols